# Calculating the mean of 200 iterations for my R Code

Tags: r, for-loop, mean, primes, sample

Question:

By generating 10,000 pairs of samples, find the probability that 2 randomly chosen integers are relatively prime (coprime).
I have been able to find if 2 numbers are co prime, but do not know how to find the mean of 200 iterations. I presume I should use a for loop but am unsure how to go about it.

this is what I have come up with so far:

```
x1<- sample(1:10000,1)
x1
x2<- sample(1:10000,1)
x2
coprime(x1,x2)
result = coprime(x1,x2)
print(result)
```

Comment: use `mean(times.coprime)` where `times.coprime` is a logical vector that has true whenever you find two coprime integers `times.coprime <- sapply(integer(200L), rand.coprime)` where rand.coprime samples two numbers and returns `result`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop if you use the `replicate` function:

```
trials <- 10000
results <- replicate(trials, coprime(sample(1:10000, 1), sample(1:10000, 1)))
sum(results/trials)
```

The value will change slightly each time you run the analysis since it is based on drawing pseudo-random numbers each time. Alternatively you can draw all of the numbers and then compute the results with `mapply` which might be faster.

```
results <- mapply(coprime, sample(1:10000, 10000, replace=TRUE), sample(1:10000, 10000, replace=TRUE))
sum(results)/trials
```